# How to turn top select option to a placeholder? contact-form-7

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, select, contact-form-7

I am trying to change the color of the first select option on my contact form to look like a placeholder.

Using contact forms 7, in wordpress, i have a select box, with 4 drop down options, select your trailer, size 1, size 2, size 3. I would like only the first option (select your trailer) to be of a placeholder color, instead of body color,

I can't seem to affect only this option...

i have tried using css, however this only affects the option in the drop down view, not the select:

```
select option:nth-child(1){
    color:red;
}
```

Then i tried a jquery script to determin the selects text color based on option selected, but alas to no avail:

```
$(".wpcf7-select").change(function(evt) {
 var selected;
 selected = $(this).val();
 if (selected === "Select Trailer Size") {
   $( select ).css( "color", "red" );
  } else {

 }
```

The site is www.kingkongdev.ml/easyfit  > then hit the book now button on the nav,

Thanks for any help, suggestions, advice!

Comment: Can you please try == instead of === may be this will help you . You can also try by console the value of selected.